# How to gracefully exit from a blocking kernel_recvmsg()?

Tags: multithreading, sockets, linux-kernel

I have the following running in a kernel thread:

```
size = kernel_recvmsg(kthread->sock, &msg, &iov, 1, bufsize, MSG_DONTWAIT)
```

I receive UDP packets very frequently (every 10ms let's say). In order to process them as fast as possible I don't have any sleep in the loop where the kernel_recvmsg() is. Unfortunately I observe very big CPU consumption while the UDP packets are not coming.
If I make the socket blocking (remove the MSG_DONTWAIT) is there some indirect way to unblock and exit from kernel_recvmsg()..?

What would happen if I do unexpected sock_release()? Should kernel_recvmsg() unblock and return some error and I could handle it accordingly (exit from the loop and thread)?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to unblock a UDP wait from another thread - sendto() it a datagram to unblock it on the local stack, ( an empty one would be fine).  You can use some 'abort' bolean flag to indicate to the post-kernel_recvmsg code to return or perform some other unusual action.

That said, there are few comms stacks on mature OS that do not unblock a socket wait if the socket is closed from another thread. I've heard on SO that this is unreliable, but I've never seen ANY case where an error return or exception is not immediately raised if the underlying socket is freed.